# How to join table if string field is not null

Tags: python, django, orm

I have to show all articles from a law. Besides that, each article can have a description or not. I have to show all articles and yours description, but I dont know how to join descriptions and article when `highlight` `description` is not null.

my `view`:

```
def details(request, pk):
 law = get_object_or_404(Law, pk=pk)    
 articles = Article.objects.filter(law=pk)
 articles = (
 Article
 .objects
 .filter(law=pk)
 .annotate(
     is_marked=Exists(
         Highlight
         .objects
         .filter(
             article_id=OuterRef('id'),
             user=request.user
         )
        )
     )
 )   
context = {
    'articles': articles,    
}
template_name = 'leis/details.html'
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

My `detail.html`:

```
<div class="article-post"> 
   {% for article in articles %}   
      {{article}}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

That's my `model`:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank = True, null=True)

class Article(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField('Artigo/Inciso')
    number = models.IntegerField('Number', blank=True, null=True)
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Law', related_name='articles')
```

This class is saved with description made by a specific user in a specific article in a specif law:

```
class Highlight(models.Model):
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Law', related_name='highlightArticles')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Article', related_name='highlightLaw')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='highlightUsers', related_name='highlightUsers')
    is_marked = models.BooleanField('Is it marked?', blank=True, default=False)
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank = True, null=True)
```

How can I join the tables to show all the articles with yours specific description made by an specific user?

Comment: when description is not null is description in `Law`? or in `Highlight`?

Comment: @NgocPham is in `Highlight`

Comment: in `Highlight` model, maybe wrong in `article` FK?

Comment: In case article fk model `Highlight` FK to `Article`. You can try `Article.objects.filter(law=pk, highlight__description__isnull=False)`. It will return all `Article` with description not null

Comment: how to show `description` in my `view`?

Comment: add this `.annotate(description=(F('highlight__description')))` in queryset . And in view you can try {{ article.description}}

Comment: it works. Tku so much. That was awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
Article.objects.filter(law=pk, highlight__description__isnull=False).annotate(description=(F('highlight__description')))
```

it will return all Article with `highlight description` is not null, and can show `description` in your view with {{ article.description }}